# "Internal error setting the array" during FBX export

Tags: export, .fbx

I am trying to export a 3D model from blender 2.81 to an FBX file.  After clicking 'Export FBX', I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\_init_.py", line 634, in execute
    return export_fbx_bin.save(self, context, **keywords)
File "C:Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3198, in save
    ret = save_single(operator, context.scene, depsgraph, filepath, **kwargs_mod)
File "C:Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 3094, in save_single
    fbx_objects_elements(root, scene_data)
File "C:Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 2894, in fbx_objects_elements
    fbx_data_mesh_elements(objects, me_obj, scene_data, done_meshes)
File "C:Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\export_fbx_bin.py", line 1163, in fbx_data_mesh_elements
    uvlayer.data.foreach_get("uv", t_luv)
RuntimeError: internal error setting the array

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

This is a .blend file I got from someone else.  The only change  made was to separate part of one of the meshes into its own mesh.  Initially, it exported to FBX with no problem.  When I went back and separated another mesh, saved, and tried to export to FBX, it started giving me this error.

I'm new to 3D modeling and blender, I have no idea what any of this code stuff means.  I've tried googling this error and I'm seeing a lot of "nevermind, fixed it" type responses without explaining what they did to fix it.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The only advice that I can give is to make sure everything is UV unwrapped.  If you need to flip normals on a surface you likely need to unwrap again.

Comment: THANK YOU so much this was so hard to find!